# HP8116A Function Generator Signal Problem

Tags: signal, measurement, oscilloscope, function-generator

I'm trying to use a function generator HP 8116A and an oscilloscope Tektronix TDS210. When i connect the probe to trigger output of function generator, i can observe  the square wave correctly.

However, if i use normal output of the function generator and send a signal of 5V and 10kHz (sinusoidal, square..) i observe this bad signal on oscilloscope display which i showed below. If you share your idea about this problem, i will be very happy.

Trigger Output (No Problem):

[image]

Sinusoidal Signal (With Problem):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I realized that the "DISABLE" mode is open on function generator. When i closed it, the signal became correct. You can see "DISABLE" button on the right side of function generator in photo. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure but it looks like your having aliasing issues. Try increasing the o-scopes sampling rate